# Querying with mongoose of dates type

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to convert parameters in request body to mongoose query to get response of the data in `mongodb` whose `"lastUpdated"` is greater than `"2018-04-03T08:01:19.269Z"`. I post the request through postman with parameters in body

```
{
    "checkedOut" : false,
    "valid" : false,
    "language" : "en",
    "lastUpdated" : "2018-04-03T08:01:19.269Z",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

the response works good in responding the data whoes `"lastUpdated"` is equal to `"2018-04-03T08:01:19.269Z"`. I write a function in my code:

```
for (const key in params) {
     if (key === "lastUpdated") {
            params[key] = {$gte : value};
     }
}
return params
```

So I got a new query:

```
{ checkedOut: false,
  valid: false,
  language: 'en',
  lastUpdated: { '$gte': '2018-04-03T08:01:19.269Z' },
  __v: 0 
}
```

But it still does not work......
please help ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `value` is a string so you should just convert it to **date** via:

```
for (const key in params) {
   if (key === "lastUpdated") {
      params[key] = {$gte : new Date(value)};
   }
}
return params
```

This way mongoDB would compare `dates with valid date`.

Comment: It is awesome and Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0):

Using query builder will solve this question:

```
const query = model.find();
        let datequery = {};
        let otherquery = {};

        for (const key in params) {
            if (key === "lastUpdated") {
                datequery[key] = params[key];
            } else {
                otherquery[key] = params[key];
            }
        }
        console.log(otherquery,datequery);
        query.where(transformCondition(otherquery));
        query.where('lastUpdated').gte(datequery['lastUpdated']);

        return query;
```